# html fluid tabular structure to present images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabular

I'm looking for a neat way to present **list of images in tabular structure.**
the catch is, it needs to adjust for low-resolution screens and window resizes (when the window is not maximized).

[Yahoo Images](http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=A0PDoKsSQXRRa1AATg.LuLkF?p=foo&ei=utf-8&fr=sfp-img&fr2=&y=Search) for example implemented it very well, though I'm looking for something simple.

How do I implement this behaviour?